# Найти 3 или больше одинаковых элемента подряд в массиве (Ревью)

Tags: php, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Есть массив из 15 элементов `['a','a','a', 'd', ... 'e']`, он подаётся на вход.

Если посмотреть по-другому, то можно представить его вот так:

---------elements----- -------keys---------------

`[a][d][e][f][a]` | `[0][3][6][9][12]`

`[a][e][f][e][g]` | `[1][4][7][10][13]`

`[a][b][b][d][e]` | `[2][5][8][11][14]`

Задача: Найти линии в которых больше чем 3 одинаковых элемента подряд. Линий всего 10: три по строкам, пять по столбцам и по диагонали `[0,4,8,10,12]`, `[2,4,6,10,14]` .

Пример: в линии `[0,1,2]` есть три одинаковых элемента (`a`), в линии `[2,4,6,10,14]` 4 элемента (`e`)

Функция возвращает линии и количество одинаковых элементов в ней.

**Вопрос**: Как можно упростить и сделать более понятной эту функцию? Не слишком ли длинный метод? Любые замечания приветсвуются.

```
public function findLines(array $input)
    {
        $checkingLines = [
            [0,1,2],
            [3,4,5],
            [6,7,8],
            [9,10,11],
            [12,13,14],
            [0,3,6,9,12],
            [1,4,7,10,13],
            [2,5,8,11,14],
            [0,4,8,10,12],
            [2,4,6,10,14]
        ];
        $lines = array();
        foreach ($checkingLines as $checkingLineNumber => $line) {
            $matchesNumber = 0;
            $matchesNumberMax = 0;
            foreach ($line as $elementNumber => $element) {
                if ($matchesNumberMax < $matchesNumber)
                    $matchesNumberMax = $matchesNumber;
                $matchesNumber = 0;
                $nextElement = $element;
                $i = $elementNumber;
                while ($input[$element] == $input[$nextElement] && $elementNumber < count($line)) {
                    $matchesNumber++;
                    $i++;
                    if (isset($line[$i]))
                        $nextElement = $line[$i];
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
            if ($matchesNumberMax >= 3) {
                $lines[$checkingLineNumber] = [
                    'elements' => $line,
                    'consecutives' => $matchesNumberMax
                ];
            }
        }
        return $lines;
    }
```

Comment: давайте сведем задачу к минимуму, в заданном массиве вам нужно определить, встречается ли там 3 и более повторяющихся значения друг за другом.

Answer (score 1):

Выделим в задаче 4 основных шага:

1. Составим линии. Вы это сделали, массивы с нужными индексами определены.
2. Определим функцию, которая будет считать повторы в простом массиве.
3. Для линии из индексов вернем реальные элементы на этих местах.
4. Проведем шаги 2-3 в цикле для всех линий

   ```
   function checkLines($input){

       $lines = [
                   [0,1,2],
                   [3,4,5],
                   [6,7,8],
                   [9,10,11],
                   [12,13,14],
                   [0,3,6,9,12],
                   [1,4,7,10,13],
                   [2,5,8,11,14],
                   [0,4,8,10,12],
                   [2,4,6,10,14]
                ];

       $check = function($line) {
                   $c = $line[0];
                   $cnt = 0;
                   foreach ($line as $el) {
                       if( $c == $el){
                           $cnt++ ;
                       }
                       else {
                           if($cnt >= 3) return $cnt;
                           $cnt = 1;
                           $c = $el;
                       }
                   }
                   return $cnt;
               };

       foreach($lines as $line){
           $data = array_intersect_key($input, array_flip($line));
           $cr = $check($data);
           if($cr >= 3){
               print_r(['line' => $line, 'count' => $cr]);
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Выглядит и правда как будто проще. А какие бы вы сделали замечания по моему варианту?

Comment: @ZhiV у вас там как-то сложно, я не разбирался :)

Comment: ну короче, большая вложенность и не разбито на блоки как у вас.